# Writing moderator expert system in OPS5

Tags: expert-system

I'm trying to build a site with automated moderation using the rule based language OPS5.

I can't seem to get the rules right as my messages are being auto banned.

```
(literalize moderator
    name
    competencelevel)
(literalize message 
    body
    ontopic
    banned)

(startup
    (make moderator ^name john ^competencelevel low)
    (make moderator ^name joe ^competencelevel low)
    (make moderator ^name bob ^competencelevel low)
    (make message ^body body1 ^ontopic yes ^banned no)  
    (make message ^body body2 ^ontopic yes ^banned no)
    (make message ^body body3 ^ontopic yes ^banned no)
    (make message ^body body3 ^ontopic no ^banned no)
)

(p rule1
    (message ^body <body> ^ontopic <ontopic> ^banned <banned>)
    (moderator ^name <name> ^competencelevel {<competencelevel> = low})
-->
    (make message ^body <body> ^ontopic <ontopic> ^banned yes)
)

(p rule2
    (message ^body <body> ^ontopic <ontopic> ^banned {<banned> = yes})
-->
    (write (crlf) |The message has been banned
           (crlf)
)
```

Comment: Rule1 stated as a pseudo-rule is "if there is a message and there is a moderator with a competence level of low, then create a new message with the same body and ontopic values and a banned value of yes." Since there are four messages and three moderators with a competence level of low, you should expect rule1 to be executed twelve times.

Comment: oh, so my expert system is working then ;)